# Scan credit or debit card in android programatically?

Tags: android

How can we scan a credit or debit card and get the information of the card for example card holder name expiry date and image of card type like visa or master card ? please give me suggesion i am new in android developing.

Comment: What have you already tried? _We are not a code service where we write you codes_.

Answer (score 3):

look at [card.io](https://www.card.io/) - they have an open-source SDK for scanning credit cards on iOS and Android.
Notice - not all of what you're asking is supported in card.io (only some types of credit cards, and they don't extract the card holder's name).

Answer (score 0):

- You can use OCR on android for extract text from image.
  First scan credit or debit card using camera in your android app and processing it through OCR.
- [Follow this link](https://community.idolondemand.com/t5/Blog/Extracting-text-from-images-using-OCR-on-Android/ba-p/1883) for how to implement OCR